# Trying to use sin on c++ receiving error message

Tags: c++, programming-languages, trigonometry

Trying to write a program in which I use sin, but I keep receiving an error message

"sin

Error: more than one instance of overloaded function "sin" matches the argument list"

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
``#include <math.h>

#define DEGREE 45
#define THREE 3

int
    main(void)
{
    double diagonal;
    double length;
    double volume;
    double stands;
    double volumeostands;

//Get # of stands
    printf("How many stands will you be making? \n");
    scanf("%d", &stands);

//Get diagonal//
    printf("What is the diagonal of the cube? \n");
    scanf("%d", &diagonal);

//Find length

    length = diagonal * sin(double(DEGREE);

//Find volume

    volume = 3(length);
//Multiply volume by number of stands

    volumeostands = volume * stands;

//Display volume (for # of stands)

    printf("Volume is %lf inches for %lf stands", &volumeostands, &stands);


        return (0);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code so we can help?

Comment: Aha! So the question really is, "What is my code?". Well I surmise that the code includes a call of a function called `sin`.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't compile and has numerous other errors such as using `%d` instead of `%f` to read/print doubles and passing the address of values to `printf` when it should just be the value.  Please post some correct code.

Answer (score 3):

That's the error message you get when the compiler can't figure out *which* overloaded function to call for your arguments and it's *usually* to do with type promotions or conversions. For example, you may have:

```
void fn(double d);
void fn(float f);
```

and, if you call `fn(x)` where `x` is neither `float` nor `double` but can equally *become* one of those types, the compiler won't know which to choose. The following program shows this scenario:

```
#include <iostream>
int x(double d) { return 1; }
int x(float f) { return 2; }
int main(){
    std::cout << x(42) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling that with `g++` results in:

```
qq.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
qq.cpp:5:20: error: call of overloaded ‘x(int)’ is ambiguous
   std::cout << x(42) << '\n';
                    ^
qq.cpp:5:20: note: candidates are:
qq.cpp:2:5: note: int x(double)
 int x(double d) { return 1; }
     ^
qq.cpp:3:5: note: int x(float)
 int x(float f) { return 2; }
```

Because you're passing an `int` value that may equally become a `float` or `double`, the compiler complains. One quick fix is to coerce the type to a *specific* one with something like:

```
std::cout << x((double)42) << '\n';
```

For your *specific* case, it may be exactly what I've shown, in that you're calling `sin()` with an integral type. Before C++11, the only overloads were for `float`, `double` and `long double`. C++11 introduced overloads for integral types that would promote them to `double` but, if you're not *on* C++11, just use the casting trick shown above.

If that *is* the case (using integral types), the first thing you should realise is that `sin()` takes its argument as the number of *radians* rather than degrees, so you will almost certainly want to use floating point (there are 360° in a circle but that's only 2π radians).

Answer (score -1):

`#include <stdio.h>`

`#include<iostream>`

`#include <math.h>`

`using namespace std;`

`#define DEGREE 45`

`#define THREE 3`

`int main(void)`
`{`

```
double diagonal;
double length;
double volume;
double stands;
double volumeostands;

//Get # of stands
cout << "How many stands will you be making? \n" ;
cin >> stands;

//Get diagonal//
cout << "What is the diagonal of the cube? \n" ;
cin >>  diagonal;

//Find length

length = diagonal * sin(DEGREE);

//Find volume

volume = 3*length;
//Multiply volume by number of stands

volumeostands = volume * stands;

//Display volume (for # of stands)

cout << "Volume is " << volumeostands << " inches for stands " << stands << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
```

`}`

Comment: Generally, answers have a description of what you've done and are formatted correctly.  The funny thing is this code is more likely to have the problem originally asked about, where the code posted in the question wouldn't if there wasn't a missing parenthesis.